# Android - horizontal images to fit screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an Android horizontal LinearLayout with 5 images in it. I want the 5 images to fit the screen horizontally while keeping the aspect ratio. Each image is 128x128 pixel. 
The problem is that while the width is set like what I wanted the **height** of the images remain the same, so they look like this on a bigger screen (this is the Nexus 7):

[image]

What I have now:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image01" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image02" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image03" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image04" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image05" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: are you ok with resizing

Answer (score 0):

change the scaleType to centerInside or fitCenter and height to match parent.

Comment: I tried that but then Android does not scale the images at all i.e. the width remains the same, only there will be spaces between them. I need the images to touch.

Comment: scaling up images and maintaining aspect ratio is not so straight forward. you'll may have to do it manually. As for touching the images to the ImageView edges goes, only centerCrop does that while maintaining aspect ratio. But it will crop out part of the image and will only do so if the image is larger than the image view, don't think it works for smaller images.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm gonna go and use minimum-height on the linearlayout with a value resource different for each screen sizes. Thats the solution I know now. Thanks for the answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

try to surround the imageview with a horizontal LinearLayout

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="btnhome" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnGames"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="btngames" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnNews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="btnnews"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnPayment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="btnpayment"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

then, change the scaleType to fitCenter.

it will cause your pictures to have a correct ratio event you view it in a wider screen.

Answer (score 0):

I found some code to create a square view that I could then use to render my own custom graphics in.  You should be able to something like this:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        int length = Math.min(width, height);
        setMeasuredDimension(length, length);
    }
}
```

I haven't tried this squaring code in a `LinearLayout` but when use `RelativeLayout` where it was positioned first and attached to three sizes of the parent it worked nicely.  This is hoping that ImageView does the right thing with the image, otherwise you're going to have to override the onDraw() method too.